# Angular Drag&Drop - Containers and Items

Tags: html, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement a Drag&Drop feature in my Angular application using the [Angular Drag&Drop](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/) library.

My requirements are similar but not as complex as in the [nested Containers Demo](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested).

In this demo the templates are implemented recursively:

```
<!-- Markup for lists inside the dropzone. It's inside a seperate template
     because it will be used recursively. The dnd-list directive enables
     to drop elements into the referenced array. The dnd-draggable directive
     makes an element draggable and will transfer the object that was
     assigned to it. If an element was dragged away, you have to remove
     it from the original list yourself using the dnd-moved attribute -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="list.html">
    <ul dnd-list="list">
        <li ng-repeat="item in list"
            dnd-draggable="item"
            dnd-effect-allowed="move"
            dnd-moved="list.splice($index, 1)"
            dnd-selected="models.selected = item"
            ng-class="{selected: models.selected === item}"
            ng-include="item.type + '.html'">
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>

<!-- This template is responsible for rendering a container element. It uses
     the above list template to render each container column -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="container.html">
    <div class="container-element box box-blue">
        <h3>Container {{item.id}}</h3>
        <div class="column" ng-repeat="list in item.columns" ng-include="'list.html'"></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</script>

<!-- Template for a normal list item -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="item.html">
    <div class="item">Item {{item.id}}</div>
</script>
```

What I need:
Two dropzones where the first can only contain containers and the second can only contain items.
The containers may only contain items and no other containers.

[image: How it should look]

How can I specify that

- Dropzone A may only contain containers
- Dropzone B may only contain items
- Containers may only contain items

In addition multi select should also be possible but I think I should be able to figure out how to implement that using the demo code.

Comment: Since this is a pretty specific question a working Plnkr would probably get more people to look at it. Since your setup is probably unique, I don't think many could replicate it correctly on their own to help get you an answer. That is, unless they have specific experience with this library.

Comment: You're right. I already thought about deleting the question because it's so specific. But I've now spent half the day trying to implement it and I get more and more familiar with the drag&drop framework. And since someone already marked it as favourite I'll post my solution tomorrow instead of deleting the question.

Comment: Did you at least get it worked out? I wouldn't mind taking a crack at it if I had your setup, hence the desire for a plnkr. If you got it figured out, I think you'd be doing someone a solid by posting the solution and accepting it when the site allows you to.